# How to get sim serial number in Windows programming 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there any API given in windows Phone 8 to get the sim serial number from the device and not the phone number.In android getSimSerialNumber() is used but i can,t find similar methods in windows phone 8 programming..

I want an unique number to identify the device in the server.so some body help me to acheive it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For security reasons, the SIM number and other personal information are not available in the public SDK for Windows Phone 8.

To uniquely identify a device you can use the [ANID2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) value.